# enableObjectResizing and enableInlineTableEditing in Webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have enabled `contentEditable`. In Firefox, by default, the tables and images can be manipulated. But in other browsers like Midori, QupZilla and similar `WebKit` browsers this feature is not enabled by default.

How/Can can I enable these two settings

1. `enableObjectResizing`
2. `enableInlineTableEditing`

in a `WebKit` based browser's console?

I am going to utilize this in a program that I am making, but trying to figure out how to do it in the console first.

Comment: I have tried document.execCommand() without any success. Does it mean it is not possible with WebKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enableObjectResizing` and `enableInlineTableEditing` aren't supported in WebKit browsers including at least Chrome. Open [this codepen](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW) (only in Chrome, obviously) to see that.